# Import Hair Into UE4

Tags: particles, export, import, hair

I am making a game in ue4 and I am trying to import my character into it. I tried to import the character into UE4 and when I did, the hair which was made by a particle system disappeared. Does anyone know how to make it not?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531

Comment: I think that might be for materials. Does anyone know how to import a hair particle system?